# List parameters of a function in C++ using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, c++, regex

I'm using javascript to parse a documentation generated with doxygen.

the functions i want to match may have the following signature:
`funcName (type1 * param1, const myNamespace::type2 param2, myNamespace::type3 param3)`

The number of parameters can vary, and i would like to get the following output (or something similar):
`[type1, const myNamespace::type2, myNamespace::type3]`

*NOTE:* I don't want to get if it's a pointer or reference

So far, here's what I tried:

```
var signature = "funcName (type1 * param1, const myNamespace::type2 param2, myNamespace::type3 param3)";
/(?:.*?)\((?:((?:const\s)?(?:\w+\:\:)?\w+)(?:.*?,\s)?)+/g.exec(signature);
```

but this only gives me the last type in my function or more exactly :
`["funcName (type1 * param1, const myNamespace::type2 param2, myNamespace::type3", "myNamespace::type3"]`

I belive my extensive use of non-greedy operators and non-capturing groups could be the source of the proble, but i'm still unable to solve that one...

*NOTE:* the use of option `/g` doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: What about things like `std::vector<...>` and such? Not an issue?

Comment: there are no templates and everything is wrapped in a typedef, but that could have been an issue indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have isolated the signature:

```js
var signature = "funcName (type1 * param1, const myNamespace::type2 param2, myNamespace::type3 param3)";
```

The following gives you the parameters:

```js
var parameters = /\((.*)\)/.exec(signature)[1];
```

Now, in the general case, you can't just `.split(",")` them, because of templated types such as `std::map<int, std::string>` for instance.

If you say there are no such templated types, then it's easy:

```js
var paramTypes = parameters.split(/\s*,\s*/).map(function(i) {
    return i.replace(/\s*[*&]*\s*\w+$/, "");
});
```

Result:

```js
["type1", "const myNamespace::type2", "myNamespace::type3"]
```

Let's look at the `\s*[*&]*\s*\w+$` regex, from the end:

- `$` makes sure we're at the end
- `\w+` matches the parameter name
- `[*&]*` matches the pointer and reference qualifiers you want to strip
- `\s*` matches possible spaces in between

This match is replaced with an empty string, so only the type name is left.

---

Now, for some fun, let's consider the nasty case:

```js
var signature = "funcName (int param1, const std::map<int, std::string>& param2, std::map<int, std::map<int, double>>& param3)";
```

This still holds:

```js
var parameters = /\((.*)\)/.exec(signature)[1];
```

For the rest, we need a state machine, which is really a very basic parser:

```js
function getArgTypes(signature) {
    var parameters = /\((.*)\)/.exec(signature)[1],
        result = [],
        level = 0,
        re = /[^<>,]+|./g,
        match,
        currentParam = "";

    while (match = re.exec(parameters)) {
        currentParam += match[0];

        switch (match[0]) {
            case "<":
                ++level;
                break;

            case ">":
                --level;
                break;

            case ",":
                if (!level) {
                    result.push(currentParam.replace(/\s*[*&]*\s*\w+\s*,$/, "").trim());
                    currentParam = "";
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    currentParam = currentParam.trim();

    if (currentParam)
        result.push(currentParam.replace(/\s*[*&]*\s*\w+\s*$/, ""));

    return result;
}
```

Result:

```js
["int", "const std::map<int, std::string>", "std::map<int, std::map<int, double>>"]
```

Not *that* complicated either :-)

The `[^<>,]+|.` regex performs *tokenization*, which means it's goal is to separate relevant bits of text into *tokens*. Note that `.` is really a shorthand for `[<>,]` in that particular case.

For this example, we're only interested in the `<`, `>` and `,` tokens. The rest can stay glued together (we can work with `std::map` for instance, no need to separate it into `std` `::` `map` like a compiler would have to do.

This should give us the following tokens:

`int param1` `,` `const std::map` `<` `int` `,` `std::string` `>` `& param2` `,` `std::map` `<` `int` `,` `std::map` `<` `int` `,` `double` `>` `>` `& param3`

Now, processing this is just a matter of tracking the nesting level.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i realize now that my main issue was to try to do everything in a single regex (which turns out too be waaay too complex). Chopping of information is also an interesting strategie. But just for my own curiosity... i wonder if this could have been achieved in a single regex.

Comment: @Xeltor not in JavaScript, its regex engine is *very* weak. But I've added a little extra to the answer to show some basic parsing :-)

Comment: Excellent and thorough discussion, and bonus +1 for using a parser. Not everything can be done with regex, and some things are better parsed even if they can be done with regex.